# R - How to build a list a character pattern in data.frame column

Tags: r, string

In R, I have the following column in my data frame...

```
bodyweight  
65lbs  
72kgs  
20kgs  
30lbs  
.
.
.
```

I want to convert it into a column with weight in numeric common unit (kgs).

Have managed to extract the numeric values from the column by using `grep()` to remove all non-numeric characters. However to convert `lbs` values in to `kgs` I need to have another column showing all cells where `lbs` is present. So the output would be something as follows...

```
bodyweight_lbs  
1  
0  
0  
1  
...
```

How do I get this output?
When I use `grep('lbs',data$bodyweight)` it returns count all `lbs` in the entire column.

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: it's r ....................

Comment: For information, the SI unit symbol is "kg", not "kgs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do like this,

```
> df <- data.frame(bodyweight=c("65lbs", "72kgs", "20kgs", "30lbs"))
> df$weight_lbs <- ifelse(grepl("lbs$", as.character(df$bodyweight)), 1, 0)
> df
  bodyweight weight_lbs
1      65lbs          1
2      72kgs          0
3      20kgs          0
4      30lbs          1
```

`grepl("lbs$", as.character(df$bodyweight))` will return `TRUE` only if the vector element contains the substring `lbs` at the last, otherwise it would return `FALSE`. By passing this inside a `ifelse` function, the above code will create a new column called `weight_lbs` and it would add the value `1` if the corresponding string in the `bodyweight` column ends with `lbs` else it would add 0.

**OR**

```
df <- data.frame(bodyweight=c("65lbs", "72kgs", "20kgs", "30lbs"))
df$weight_lbs <- as.numeric(grepl("lbs$", as.character(df$bodyweight)))
```